# Replacing newline character in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping

I am trying to replaces instances of `\r` or `\n` characters in my json object with `<br />` for display on a website.

I tried:

```
myString = myString.replace("\\r?\\n", "<br />");
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. When I replace the regex with something else (like `"a"` for instance, the replace works as expected).  Any ideas why this isn't working for the newline chars?

Comment: Why not just dump the string into a `<pre>` instead, which preserves white space?

Comment: ...Or use CSS `white-space: pre;` on whatever element you are filling with the text

Answer (score 52):

Try this:

```
myString = myString.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "<br />");
```

**Update**:
As told by Pointy on the comment below, this would replace a squence of `\r\n` with two `<br />`, the correct regex should be:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: This will work, but it's probably **not** exactly what the OP wants.  The almost-regex in the question is close: `/\r?\n/g` will replace any single line feed character *optionally* preceded by a carriage return character, with a single `<br>`.  Your regex, on the other hand, would replace a CR-LF sequence with **two** `<br>` tags.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I've read "\r or \n" no the question, and didn't think about it. going to fix the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
 white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Is a far more eficient method.

Answer (score 2):

try `replace(/\r\n|\n/, '<br />')`

Comment: This only replaced the first occurance for me. Change it to this to replace all new lines:
replace(/\r\n|\n/g, "<br />");

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
str = str.replace(/\\n|\\r\\n|\\r/g, '<br/>');
```

Using double slash